# Can't handshake with my node

Tags: bitcoin-core

I have a 0.11 nodes, all was fine until now, no restart is doing anything.

My client sends a Version Handshake but the ACK never comes.
In RPC getpeerinfo take 1 or 2 minutes to process even if there is only one connected node.

I was 0.10 before and noticed the problem, so I updated to 0.11 but it makes no difference. I am kind of stuck now. My Testnet node, on the same machine works perfectly.

No special errors in the logs, the node seems to get synchronized.

Comment: Very strange, I had to wait 30 min and it suddenly woke up and now works correctly oO That's the first time it get so slow... [EDIT] It woke up, spitted AcceptToMempool error message, accepted connection for 2 min and is now back to sleep, not accepting handshakes -_- [EDIT2] It is alternating... woke phase, everything works fine, lots of AcceptToMempool failures but Handshakes passing, then sleep phase... When it goes from awake to sleep, the connection which wait handshake are all dropped.

Comment: Are you running out of memory?

Comment: no, if I did I would expect my testnet node on the same box to also have problem, or that rebooting the main node (which trash mempool) would also have fixed.

I'll close issue for now, it seems to have resolved by itself. I've gone to bed  and when I woke up, it started working again...

Comment: Well, this time it works, my fix was : "going to bed and see tomorrow".
I'm not yet sure about what caused that. If it happens again, I'll ty to track it down.